# Match expressions for different postfix and suffix

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace part of a String if the value is within % symbols.

So for example the following String.

```
other text%original text%other text
```

After replacing it, I should get

```
other textreplaced textother text
```

I am able to achieve this via the following:

```
String newStr = "other text%original text%other text".replaceFirst("%.*%", "replaced text");
```

But the % symbol is not always guaranteed to come in as %. It might be in ASCII format as follows.

```
other text&#37;original text&#37;other text
```

Now I could write it twice like the following.

```
String toBeReplaced = //

String newStr = toBeReplaced.replaceFirst("%.*%", "replaced text");
newStr = "other toBeReplaced.replaceFirst("&#37;.*&#37;", "replaced text");
```

But is there a way I could modify the regex so that I can just perform the replacement once to cover both scenarios?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex in java, `other textreplaced textother text` is the result.

```
String str1 = "other text%original text%other text";
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("\\%.*?%", "replaced text"));

String str2 = "other text&#37;original text&#37;other text";
System.out.println(str2.replaceAll("\\&#37;.*?&#37;", "replaced text"));


System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("(\\%.*?%)|(\\\\&#37;.*?&#37;)", "replaced text"));
```

Comment: Thanks but you've provided 2 different regex. I am looking for 1 regex which captures both scenarios.

Comment: @Fllappy just add or condition to the regex, thanks~ (\\%.*?%)|(\\\\&#37;.*?&#37;) indeed